# Jquery Isotope filtering pushes items outside my container

Tags: jquery-isotope

When I use Jquery Isotope filtering, the result pushes my .items outside my #container. http://petersonspace.com/tss/media/ Here's the JS...

```
    var $container = $('#container');
    // init
    $container.isotope({
        // options
        itemSelector: '.item',
        layoutMode: 'masonry',
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: '.item'
        }
    });

    $('#filters').on('click', 'span', function () {
        var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: filterValue
        });
});
```

I've tried many different variable for the columnWidth option because I think that's where my issue lies, but I'm not sure. it's currently set to .item, but it's been 400, 250, .custom-resize-class and $container.find('.item')[0]... none of them worked. I want the .items to stay in their 1200px wide container after a filter is clicked.